# using composition to create properties

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, inheritance, composition

I currently have a datecreated property on all my POCO classes.

I am wondering if there is another way to do this.

I have looked at inheritance but I can only inherited from one base class so I don't want to use inheritance as I may need to use that for other purposes.

I have looked at composition but that does not create the properties on each class.

Just looking for advice on a strategy for achieving this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you create one base-class. If all of your POCO-entities are going to need it, that's exactly what you want.

It's correct that a class can inherit only from one base-class, but you can still create a chain of inheritance:

```
public class EntityBase
{
    public DateTime DateCreated {get; set; }
}
```

Example:

```
public class Person : EntityBase
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    // other properties
}

public class Employee : Person
{
     public decimal Salary {get; set; }
}
```

Now `Person` as well as `Employee` have a `DateCreated` property, but `Employee` also inherits the `Name` of `Person`